# Why math.trunc do not work as expected in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I try to run the following. I was expecting the integer part (151511919299292911851) but I get a value of 151511919299292921856 that is -10005 less than what I expected.

```
import math
math.trunc(float('151511919299292911851.06'))
```

Comment: Floating-point numbers don't have infinite precision. You only get as much precision as is available from the bits in the mantissa. Just print out `float('151511919299292911851.06')` you'll see it's already a different value form what you put in. You get less than 16 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: In your case, you should rather cut the original string at the decimal point, then convert to int.

Comment: Ah, the irony of an overflow question on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @M-Chen-3 this isn't integer or stack overflow, it's a float precision problem. What about this makes you think overflow?

Comment: @RandomDavis Well, it's sort of similar to overflow. I don't actually know very much about overflow.

Comment: @RandomDavis It's overflowing the available precision.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the limited precision (usually 53 significant bits) supported by `float` values. To avoid this, use the arbitrary-precision `Fraction` class from Python's `fractions` module:

```
In [32]: from fractions import Fraction                                         

In [35]: import math                                                            

In [38]: math.trunc(Fraction('151511919299292911851.06'))                       
Out[38]: 151511919299292911851

In [39]: math.trunc(float('151511919299292911851.06'))                          
Out[39]: 151511919299292921856

In [40]: math.trunc(float('-151511919299292911851.06'))                         
Out[40]: -151511919299292921856

In [41]: math.trunc(Fraction('-151511919299292911851.06'))                      
Out[41]: -151511919299292911851
```