# How to convert very small numbers from strings to floats properly in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion, precision, maya

I have a number like this:

```
n = "0.000016495822225857"
```

But after converting this to a float using:

```
num = float(n)
```

I get:

```
1.64958e+13
```

My number is less than 1, how can I convert it properly so that I can round these values that are less than 1? But right now after conversion, it's greater than 1.

Is this because of floating point precision?

Comment: How did you check that value is `1.64958e+13`? `print(num)` gives `1.6495822225857e-05` for me. Could you show reproducible example? Looks like you are using only `000016495822225857` part. Lost DecimalSeparator?

Comment: I was printing the value to the console, that's how I saw it but I am using a python embedded inside another app called Maya.

Comment: In any case this is not precision problem but wrong interpretation of string

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571506/why-math-trunc-do-not-work-as-expected-in-python/66572086#66572086

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No clue why this is happening (sorry about that).

What I do know is that you can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module as a workaround.

```
from decimal import Decimal
n = "0.000016495822225857"
d = Decimal(n)
```

output

```
0.000016495822225857
```

If I'm not blind, the input and output look the same.

Comment: Is there a 2.7 version of this?